# Method ignores class scope variable value change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scope, boolean, global-variables

The issue is with the boolean `isDodging`. It is set to true in the  `Dodge()` method. That should trigger an if statement in the `Movement()` method (called in `FixedUpdate()`) but that block is always skipped over. I'm attaching all of the class' code, because there must be something I'm missing here:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementController
{
    /* COMPONENTS */
    public Rigidbody2D Rigidbody { private get; set; }

    /* VARIABLES */
    private bool isDodging = false;
    private Vector2 dodgeDirection = Vector2.right;
    private float dodgeDuration = 1f;
    private float dodgeSpeed = 20f;
    private float timer = 0f;

    /* METHODS */
    
    // Called in fixed update (since it's dealing with physics)
    public void Movement(Vector2 currentPosition, Vector2 velocity)
    {
        Debug.Log("In movement: " + isDodging);
        if (isDodging)
        {
            Debug.Log("Dodge 3");
            Move(currentPosition, dodgeDirection * dodgeSpeed);

            timer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            if (timer >= dodgeDuration)
            {
                Debug.Log("Stopped dodging " + Time.fixedTime);
                isDodging = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Move(currentPosition, velocity);
        }
    }

    private void Move(Vector2 currentPosition, Vector2 velocity)
    {
        if (Rigidbody == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No rigidbody to move!");
            return;
        }

        Rigidbody.MovePosition(currentPosition + (velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }

    // Must be called while Movement is being called
    public void Dodge(Vector2 direction, float maxSpeed, float speedMultiplier = 2f, float duration = 1f)
    {
        if (direction == Vector2.zero) { return; }
        Debug.Log("Dodge 1 " + isDodging);

        dodgeDirection = direction;
        dodgeDuration = duration;
        dodgeSpeed = maxSpeed * speedMultiplier;

        isDodging = true;
        Debug.Log("Dodge 2" + isDodging + Time.fixedTime);
        
        timer = 0f;
    }
}
```

The thing is, the "In movement: " log always shows isDodging as `false`, and the if block under it never runs. Meanwhile, "Dodge 2" will show `true` (as `isDodging` is changed right above it). And the weirdest: "Dodge 1" shows `false` the first time `Dodge()` is called, but `true` everytime its called after that - as if `isDodging` was changed to true in the class scope, and `Movement()` doesn't recognize that for some reason.

Both this functions are called in a separate MonoBehaviour:

```
public class CreatureMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement")]
    [SerializeField] protected Vector2Reference moveDirection;
    [SerializeField] protected FloatReference maxSpeed;

    [Header("Dodge")]
    [SerializeField] private FloatReference dodgeDuration;
    [SerializeField] private FloatReference dodgeSpeedMultiplier;

    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private new Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    private readonly MovementController movement = new MovementController();

    public float MaxSpeed { get => maxSpeed; }

    private float speed;
    private float Speed { get => speed; set => speed = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, maxSpeed); }

    public virtual Vector2 Velocity
    {
        get => moveDirection.Value * Speed;
        set
        {
            moveDirection.SetValue(value.normalized);
            Speed = value.magnitude;
        }
    }

    private void Start() => movement.Rigidbody = rigidbody;
    private void FixedUpdate() => movement.Movement(transform.position, Velocity);

    public void Dodge() => movement.Dodge(moveDirection, maxSpeed, dodgeSpeedMultiplier, dodgeDuration);
}
```

Where `Dodge()` is called from player input.

Except for dodging, movement is ocurring exactly as expected. The problem probably isn't in the `Move()` method, as it doesn't have `isDodging` in it.

I have absolutey no idea why this is happening, the code seems so simple to me, but it just isn't working. Please help out with this.

Comment: Sometimes there issue is where you don't think it is :). If you knew where the problem was, you'd resolve it yourself. Removing code stops us from determining exactly what's going on.

Comment: I don't use Unity so I have to ask, unfortunately, is `isDodging` being accessed by multiple threads?  If unsure, I would also debug log the thread you're on when accessing.

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec you're absolutely right! I edited the question to show the entire code now.

Comment: @Zer0 I am not entirely sure. I have not explicitely coded anything related to threads, but it might be the case that Unity does that under the hood. I would have to look deeper into Unity's inner workings.

Comment: You can use `Thread.CurrentThread` to get information on the thread you're on.  In case you haven't noticed I'm first trying to eliminate any threading issues.  If that _is_ being accessed by multiple threads then code changes are necessary.

Comment: @Zer0 I'm not sure if this is how you check this, but what I did was print `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` in the "In movement" and the "Debug 1" logs. Both times the ID was the same (1).

Comment: If you're not 100% sure you could do `private volatile bool isDodging = false;`.  If you want to be certain you're reading the latest value you could use `Thread.VolatileRead` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `Dodge` on a prefab instead of the scene instance of that prefab which is running `CreatureMovement.FixedUpdate`.

I believe you can verify this by placing this code in `Dodge` (Source: [Max-Pixel](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1190932/view.html)):

```
if (gameObject.scene.name == null) Debug.Log("It's a prefab!");
```

You need to change your input processing to call `Dodge` on the instance in the scene instead of a prefab.

You can do that by dragging the instance in the scene into the button onclick event, then selecting `Dodge`. Or, if you are spawning the object dynamically, you could, in `Start`, find a reference to the button, and add `Dodge` to its `onClick` listeners:

```
private void Start()
{
    movement.Rigidbody = rigidbody;  
    // something along the lines of this...
    Button buttonRef = GameObject.Find("ButtonName").GetComponent<Button>();

    buttonRef.onClick.AddListener(Dodge);
}
```

Comment: You are right, thank you! I placed that line on the `CreatureMovement.Dodge()` method, and got the log.

If anyone is wondering, to fix it I just had to, in the inspector, drag the reference of the instance to the script where `CreatureMovement.Dodge()` is called. It somehow was referencing the prefab, although I hadn't manually set that. This was driving me crazy, and you hit the nail right on the head. Thank you so much!